# display border only if element is not a tfoot element

Tags: css

I want to display a `border` for a `td` element, but only if the element is **not** in a `tfoot` element. How do I do that with the `.not` CSS selector?

This doesn't work:

```
td.not(tfoot) { ... }
```

Comment: Is `tfoot` class on `table` or on `td`?

Comment: `tfoot`is an html tag, a `table` section

Answer (score 2):

You can try this rule (affects all cells that are not in tfoot)

```
table :not(tfoot) tr td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

or

```
table > :not(tfoot) td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply border only to tbody or thead with this code:

```
table thead tr th{
    border: 1px solid #ccc; // Here your code of css
}

table tbody tr td{
    border: 1px solid #ccc; // Here your code of css
}
```

Regards!

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer the question directly, it does indeed solve my problem - thanks. +1 for thinking out of the box

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly do that. What you can do, however, is to set and then overwrite a rule:

```
td { border: 1px solid black; }
tfoot td { border-width: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, that's always the safe option, but I wanted a more elegant solution utilising CSS capabilities.